# Different fuctions to confirm deployment with ethersjs

Tags: ethers.js

I saw there are two functions with ethers what are the difference between these two:

```
await contract.deployTransaction.wait()
```

vs

```
 await contract.deployed();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `contract.deployed()` using `deployTracsaction.wait()` but add more case, you can look at the source

[image]